# Writting React Native with android and iOS code in the same code base?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, react-native

Looking through the documentation (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) it seems you need 2 different files ones with file ending in `.ios` the other `.android`

I find it hugely confusing now I'm starting to write code do I need 2 repos to write this code

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you do need to write to the specific platform you are working on at the time. If you are working on iOS / Xcode, then the .ios files will automatically be the once run when compiled, and vice versa.

If you are not writing any platform specific code, you can copy the code from whatever components are working on in your current platform over to the other platform, and they should work fine there.

Comment: Copy and paste code is totally a good solution?  Can you sym link across the projects maybe so you really only have one file?

Comment: Sure, any way you would like to get the code to the other file. Copy and pasting is probably not the optimal solution, but to get started it certainly works!

Answer (score 2):

You could use some strategy to share the same code base.

I found a project where it was made:

> **Mobile, desktop and website Apps with the same code** -
>   https://github.com/benoitvallon/react-native-nw-react-calculator